# count dynamic number of input elements on dom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can count all input elements with has id which starting with (myInputElem) inside dom using jquery. So there will be dynamic number of input elements like

```
<input id="myInputElem1" type="text" value="Eleme1">
<input id="myInputElem2" type="text" value="Eleme2">
..
<input id="myInputElemx" type="text" value="Elemex">
```

So I just need to count them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and then get the length

```
$('[id^="myInputElem"]').length
```

Answer (score 4):

use attribute starts with selector `^`.

If you want to use the ends with selector, use `$`

```
$("[id^='myInputElem']").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even u can try this

```
$('[value^="Eleme"]').length
```